# Remove the Open and close brackets from the string

Tags: python, list

I want to remove the [ ] brackets from list1 variable in python

```
list1 = ['Order No','Item']
```

Expected :

```
>>> print (list1)
'Order No', 'Item'
```

Actual :

```
>>> print (list1)
['Order No', 'Item']
```

Comment: `', '.join(list1)` ?

Comment: `print (list1[0], list1[1])` ?

Comment: You do know that the brackets are printed, only when you print the list. They don't actually exist in the actual list.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
>>> list1 = ['Order No','Item']
>>> print(str(list1)[1:-1])
'Order No', 'Item'
>>>
```

If you don't need the quotes, use:

```
>>> print(', '.join(list1))
Order No, Item
```

Comment: The question isn't really clear from the OP

Comment: Hi u9, I am getting as below "'Order No', 'Item'" . I need 'order No', 'item'

Comment: @Mahesh Will edit

Comment: @Mahesh Now, please accept :-)

Comment: Again getting same.. >>> list1 = ['Order No','Item']
>>>
>>>
>>> abc = str(list1)[1:-1].lower()
>>>
>>> abc
"'order no', 'item'"

Comment: @Mahesh Oh!!! because you need `print(abc)`!!

Comment: @U9-Forward, I want to pass the value in one variable with out double quotes. abc = 'Order no' , 'item'

Comment: @Mahesh It's the same thing! double-quotes show up only if you print it!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for i in list1:
 print("'" + i + "'")
```

if you don't want the braces:

```
for i in list1:
 print(i)
```